# react-select "cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to implement 'react-select' but I am getting a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'. On selecting the value from select box, handleSelectInput event gets called but it is not setting selectedType state variable to the selected value.
What is wrong in the code?

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  {value:'sqFeet',label:'Square Feet'},
  {value:'acre',label:'Acre'},
  {value:'cent',label:'Cent'}
]
class RegisterProperty extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selectedType:''
        }
        this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleSelectChange(event) {   
        console.log(event) //prints the selected option     
        this.setState({
            selectedType:event.target // selectedType is undefined
        })      
    }
    render() {
        return(
          <div id="content">
            <form onSubmit={(event) => {
               event.preventDefault()
               const propertyType = this.state.selectedType
               console.log(propertyType) // prints undefined
            <div className="col-sm-3"><Select options={options} onChange={this.handleSelectChange} />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Register Property</button>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi try `event.target.value` ;)

Comment: pass `value=this.state.selectedType` on Select as  `<Select options={options} onChange={this.handleSelectChange}  value={this.state.selectedType} />`

Comment: facing the same issue even after adding event.target.value and value={this.state.selectedType} in Select